# Binary Calculator subtraction

Tags: c++, binary, calculator, subtraction

I am currently doing a project for my school which is about Binary Numbers. I have already made an addition Calculator which works fine and now I'm trying to make one for subtraction. There I'm facing some problems. The biggest one is that I get negative numbers as output and when I use the `binary 2's complement` I don't get any negative results but they are still wrong. Example: When substracting `110010`(50) with `11110`(30) my output is `10-1-100` instead of `10100`.
When transforming 30 in 2nd complement `(00010)` my output is `110000` which is 48 in decimal

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    long a, b;
    int i = 0, r = 0, sub[20];
    cout << "1st number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "2nd number: ";
    cin >> b;
    while (a != 0 || b != 0)
    {
        sub[i++] = (a % 10 - b % 10 + r) % 2;
        r = (a % 10 - b % 10 + r) / 2;
        a = a / 10;
        b = b / 10;
    }
    if (r != 0)
        sub[i++] = r;
    --i;
    cout << "Difference: ";
    while (i >= 0)
        cout << sub[i--];
    cout << ". ";


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If ever there was a question deserving of tested input, expected output, and actual output, this is it. [Update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63963869/edit) to include that information.

Comment: IMHO, inputting the numbers as `std::string` will make playing with digits (or bits) easier.  For example, the value of a bit in the string is: `unsigned int bit_value = input_string[x] - '0';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the subtraction, I can see that you're only comparing the numbers bit by bit, and if one of the bits in the 1st number is `0` and the corresponding bit in the 2nd number is `1`, it will just do `0 - 1 = -1`, without considering the other digits of the number.

Adding a condition that changes the other numbers when the current number is negative should solve the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long a, b;
    int i = 0, r = 0, sub[20];
    cout << "1st number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "2nd number: ";
    cin >> b;
    while (a != 0 || b != 0)
    {
        sub[i] = (a % 10 - b % 10 + r) % 2; //Change the "i++" and put "i".
        r = (a % 10 - b % 10 + r) / 2;
        //Add this:
        while(sub[i - 1] < 0)
        {
            sub[i-1] += 2;
            sub[i]--;
        }
        //Until here
        a = a / 10;
        b = b / 10;
        i++; //Increment "i" here.
    }
    if (r != 0)
        sub[i++] = r;
    --i;
    //Add this if you want to ignore the leading 0's:
    while (i >= 1 && sub[i] == 0)
        i--;
    //Until here.
    cout << "Difference: ";
    while (i >= 0)
        cout << sub[i--];
    cout << ". ";


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

About transforming numbers in 2nd complement. How the input is supposed to be?